# QNetworkAccessManager get called in a QThread because cyclic

Tags: get, qthread, qnetworkaccessmanager

I need to call a web request cyclically, so, the easy way to do that is, of course, create a thread and call my request followed by a sleep..
The issue is that I wrote my code and it basically works. When I try to call the get inside a QThread, I don't receive any result, the event associated to the response is never invoked:

```
class RemoteControl : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager;

public:
    explicit RemoteControl(QObject* parent = 0); 
    ~RemoteControl() {}

public slots:
    void process() {
        std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

        while (true)    {
            execute();
            std::cout << "called" << std::endl;
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
    void execute() {
        QUrl url("my request for num of visitors that works..");
        QNetworkRequest req;
        req.setUrl(url);
        req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(req);
    }
    void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
        std::cout << "finished called" << std::endl;
        QByteArray resp = reply->readAll();
        std::cout << resp.data() << std::endl;
    }

signals:
    void finished();

    private:
    WebRequest* WebReq_;
};


RemoteControl::RemoteControl(bool* enable, LoggerHandle* Log, QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    enable_ = enable;
    Log_    = Log;
    running_ = false;
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,
       SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

int main() {
    //.... my code....

    QThread* t3 = new QThread;
    RemoteContr->moveToThread(t3);
    QObject::connect(t3, SIGNAL(started()), RemoteContr, SLOT(process()));
    t3->start();

    //.... my code....
}
```

So, what happens is that using this code I didn't get any errors, in the output I can see `start` and `called` but never `finished called`..
it seems that the event `downloadFinished` is never called.

Can you help me to understand why?
Something wrong in my class RemoteControl?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a thread for this.  The `QNetworkAccessManager` is asynchronous, so the calls you're using do not block.  Instead of a thread, just do something like this in your main function:

```
QTimer * timer = new QTimer; 
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), RemoteContr, SLOT(execute());
timer->start(5000);  // = 5 seconds
```

Then, `execute` is invoked every 5 seconds, which seems to be what you want.

By the way, I think the reason you aren't getting results is that the `while` loop in `process` is blocking the thread.  You can get rid of the `process` slot with this approach.

Comment: Interesting.. I will check. Just an additional question because I never used QTimer: the signal is timeout(), it means that after 5 seconds it calls the execute method and that it dies, or timers works cyclically? I wrote while loop because I need the request called in loop..

Comment: The timer will emit the signal every 5 seconds until you call its `stop` method.  You can change that behavior with `setSingleShot`, but the default is to emit the `timeout()` signal periodically.